# Skip automatically pop up for protected workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I use at the moment the following command to open a set of workbooks one by one:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fFile, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, ReadOnly:=False
```

Normally the files are open in `write-enabled` mode, which is what I want. But for some files, the previous line pops up the following window:

[image]

In this case, I need to press `Read Only` to open it. Even though it is `read-only`, it is still good to be able to open it.

So to conclude, I try to open files in `write-enabled` mode, if it is not possible for some files, opening them in `read-only` is still fine. But as the number of the files is huge, I really want to automatize it, and avoid this pop-up. Could anyone tell me how to do it?

One possible turnaround is to first opening all the files in `read-only` mode, then convert them to `write-enabled` mode if possible. Do you think that is doable?

Comment: You can use the notify option within the workbooks.open method to open without the prompt in read only mode. IE Workbooks.Open Filename:=fFile, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, Notify:=True...Notify mode:If the file cannot be opened in read/write mode, this argument is True to add the file to the file notification list. Microsoft Excel will open the file as read-only, poll the file notification list, and then notify the user when the file becomes available. If this argument is False or omitted, no notification is requested, and any attempts to open an unavailable file will fail.

Comment: @KazJaw - If it is reserved due to being open by another user, that does not trigger a password prompt. Here is the link with all the options for workbooks.open http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819.aspx - Google is your friend

Comment: @Sorceri I tried `Workbooks.Open Filename:=fFile, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, ReadOnly:=False, notify:=False` and `Workbooks.Open Filename:=fFile, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever, ReadOnly:=False, notify:=True`, the window always pops up... Do you know why?

Comment: try turning off alerts: Application.DisplayAlerts = false

Comment: @Sorceri that does not help...

Comment: You need to change this: ReadOnly:=False to this: ReadOnly:=True

Comment: @AlanWaage For most of my files, I still want them to be opened in `write-enabled` mode...

Comment: You cannot have it both ways. If the file has a password saved on it, you have to either provie the PW, or be in ReadOnly mode. Those are the only ways to bypass being prompted. Note: Even in ReadOnly mode you can still saveas to another filename.  If you are looking for a way to 'detect' which files need this added clause, that is something I do not know how to do.  I expect it would be parsing the .xml inside the .xlsx file maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible workaround for you. The idea is to pass any incorrect password to `WriteResPassword argument`. If file is protected the error will be thrown. If so you will be able to identify that file and open it in `read-only mode`. Alternatively, password will be ignored for other files and fill will be open for `read-write mode`.

Some additional comments within code below.

```
Sub PossibleWorkaround()

    Dim Pass As String
    'any password
    Pass = "blahblah"

    'file which is write-protected will throw error during opening it _
    with incorrect password
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open "c:\users\alpha\desktop\filename.xlsx", , , , , Pass
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        'if so, try to open it in read-only mode
        Workbooks.Open "c:\users\alpha\desktop\filename.xlsx", , True
    End If
    'return to standard error handling or set as expected
    On Error GoTo 0



    'the same for file which is not write-protected
    'incorrect password will be ignored
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open "c:\users\alpha\desktop\filename A.xlsx", , , , , Pass
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        'therefore this if statement will not be called
        Workbooks.Open "c:\users\alpha\desktop\filename.xlsx", , True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but the problem is, when it runs to `Workbooks.Open "c:\users\alpha\desktop\filename.xlsx", , , , , Pass`, the window pops up, and it does not throw an error...

Comment: can you copy the real code of yours for that line here to comment?

Comment: which office version you run?

Comment: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=fFile, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever` is the real code. And I am using Excel 2010...

Comment: I meant the line of my idea- the way you implemented it. What you have copy to comment is not the idea I propose...

Comment: let me add it- I did tested this code and I believe it's working just as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tired to find the answer on many formums and nothing. Finally I added  WriteResPassword:="password here" in the end of the Worksbooks.Open statement and it did not prompt for a password anymore

Workbooks.Open Filename:="\path to the file\File_name.xlsm", Password:="password here", WriteResPassword:="password here"